# What is meaning of messages: string[] = []; in angular class?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am very new to Angular and JavaScript. I did not under stand the meaning of this statement. Please describe meaning of it.

`messages: string[] = [];`

Comment: messsages is a class property which will be an array of strings and is initialized as an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying that the class property **messages** can only receive an **array of strings** and initializing it as an **empty array**.

Comment: Nitpick: instance property, not variable.

Answer (score 0):

A variable called `messages` is being created and initialized to an empty list `= []`.
The `: string[]` part tells typescript compiler that variable `messages` is a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate in detail;

In typescript we can declare class properties (or simply variables) in the following way:

```
[public|private] varName [:validType] [= someValue]
```

the parts are explained as:

- [public|private] are access modifiers and tell whether the property
  is available outside of the class or not, takes value of public or
  private, if you not supply it will be public by default
- the varName part is any **valid** variable name
- the :validType is any datatype or array of valid datatype, its optional but recommended the
  list part is intializing the variable with some value and is optional
  example:

```
public message: string = null;
private messages: string[] = [];
```